# About getting a window handle in Visual Studio 2012 C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a problem with visual studio 2012 c + +. When I create a window form and add a textbox (with drag and drop), I use the FindWindow function but could not get the handle of the textbox because I could not find the window class, and I also can not use the GetDlgItem function because I can not find the ID of the textbox. So how can I get the window handle of the textbox or other? Thank you!

Comment: You're attempting to use C++ to find a child window on a Windows Forms dialog box?

Comment: Winforms dynamically generates the window class name.  It is never the same.  Which means that you cannot use FindWindow.  It is entirely unclear why you think you need to use it, get ahead by not forgetting that you've added a textbox.

Comment: Yes man, I try to find handle of a textbox (in a window form) that I created before,  but there is no ID, so I can't use GetDlgItem, what function can I use to find the handle?